# Using JS Regex to obtain the first value proceeding a string with dynamic trailing values

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Given the following string variations:

```
var string = "groups/Da12312a"
var string = "groups/Da12312a/search"
var string = "groups/Da12312a/search/sam"
var string = "groups/3131"
var string = "groups/444/search"
var string = "groups/123asdadsZad/search/sam"
```

How can I get back just the value following groups/ and ending at the first '/'?

desired output:

```
Da12312a
Da12312a
Da12312a
3131
444
123asdadsZad
```

Using jQuery or JavaScript? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `split` method.

```
string.split("/")[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var output = string.split('/')[1];
```

[`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) reference.

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y65UG/1/) with your provided examples and output.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a simple regular expression.

```
var str = 'groups/foo';
var matches = /groups\/([^/]*)/.exec(str);
```

**matches** will now contain an array where index 0 is "groups/100" and index 1 is "foo".

```
["groups/foo", "foo"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a regex, you can use the following:

```
/^[^\/]*?\/([^\/]*).*/
```

Basically the captured group yields your desired result.

Use like:

```
"groups/Da12312a/search".match(/^[^\/]*?\/([^\/]*).*/)
["groups/Da12312a/search", "Da12312a"]

"groups/Da12312a".match(/^[^\/]*?\/([^\/]*).*/)
["groups/Da12312a", "Da12312a"]

"groups/3131".match(/^[^\/]*?\/([^\/]*).*/)
["groups/3131", "3131"]
```

As you can see, in each of the cases the array index [1] is your result.

Hope that helps.